# On-Demand Resource .. Invalid Tag "The requested application data doesn’t exist."

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin.ios

I have an app on the app store that uses On-Demand resources. I have 12 videos with the tags Video1, Video2, Video3, etc..  I am using Sentry IO to log exceptions and I sporadically receive the following exceptions when users are fetching the videos (occurs on beginAccessingResources):

Invalid Tag:

```
NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4994 "The requested application data doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x2808f40f0 {Error Domain=_NSBundleResourceRequestErrorDomain Code=100 "No manfiest found for bundle ID com.nscorp.eam.caruat" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=No manfiest found for bundle ID com.nscorp.eam.caruat}}}
```

Notice, com.nscorp.eamcaruat is not the bundleID for my app which explains why there is no manifest found containing my tag. The tag itself is not invalid. I'm logging that too and every time this occurs the tag is correct, but the bundle ID is not that of my app.

Most users don't experience this. I can confirm that the majority of the time these videos are retrieved successfully. However, when it fails it's always with some bundle ID other than my app's. Here are some other examples:

"No manfiest found for bundle ID com.wjj.xie"
"No manfiest found for bundle ID com.linhwa.LHOA"

This is very sporadic and there's no way for me to reproduce it locally on demand (pun not intended).

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks!

Sean

Comment: are you distributing the source code or hosting your IPA? it almost looks like someone has swapped out their own bundle ID for yours.

Comment: Not distributing the source code..  Just a regular app store app with Apple hosted On-Demand resources..  Not sure what you mean by "hosting your IPA".. I guess no to that. Apple is hosting it (if I understand your question correctly)

Comment: By hosting your IPA I meant ad hoc distribution, but sounds like you're not doing that. My best guess is that people are downloading your app on jailbroken devices, modifying your settings to run it with their own development teams. 

There's s number of things you can do to prevent use on jailbroken devices, which you should look into if you're concerned about that.

Comment: I was beginning to wonder if that might be the case. Can you offer any references to documentation/articles on how to prevent this? Also, how would someone be acquiring a free version of my app anyway?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of visual-studio? See [this thread](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/8026) may help.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio for Mac. I do have random issues adding On-Demand resources to my project. I've been planning to open some bug tickets on it hopefully showing the team how to reproduce it. I'll try to upgrade later before I do that. However, in this case, it's hard to imagine VS being the problem because when I test my own app on the app store or test flight, everything works. My analytics show that 99.99% of the time, my users are successfully accessing all ODR. I'll check out the link. Thanks Jack!

Comment: Yes, it would be better if you can reproduce the issue on your side as it only happens at 0.01% of the time.